# How to insert a vertical rule in a resume latex

Tags: color, rules, cv

I am designing my resume on latex and I need to put a colored vertical rule in my resume like this light green rule in this  CV

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the layout sorted, placement of a vertical rule along the left side of the page can be done by [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}% Your resume class

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum}

\newlength{\siderulewidth}\setlength{\siderulewidth}{25pt}
\definecolor{siderulecolor}{RGB}{139,196,128}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \color{siderulecolor}\rule{\siderulewidth}{\paperheight}%
  }
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]% Your resume

\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to add some content to the vertical bar:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}% Your resume class

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,graphicx,lipsum}

\newlength{\siderulewidth}\setlength{\siderulewidth}{25pt}
\definecolor{siderulecolor}{RGB}{139,196,128}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \rotatebox{90}{\colorbox{siderulecolor}{\makebox[\dimexpr\paperheight-2\fboxsep]{%
      \Large
      \rule[-.4\baselineskip]{0pt}{1.4\baselineskip}% strut
      \textcolor{white}{Curriculum vitea}%
    }}}
  }
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]% Your resume

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Could we write a center vertical text like "Curriculum vitae"

Comment: @BetterEnglish: See the updated answer.

Comment: it does not work! it is an horizontal bar

Comment: @BetterEnglish: Then why does it work in my minimal example?

Comment: @Werner How to shift this green side rule forward by about 1cm so that it just touches the left side of the paragraph--so blank space 1cm+green vertical rule