# How to insert a text in \rule

Tags: rules, text, cv

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

I need to insert text inside the rule.

Comment: `\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4mm}
text between rules\par
\noindent\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}` ?

Comment: Is this different from you [other request](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336934/how-to-insert-a-vertical-rule-in-a-resume-latex#comment826406_336943)?

Comment: Do you want text to be written *within* the rule? If you're using a rule of thickness/width `0.4mm`, the text will be quite small. Or do you just want the text written with rules above and below?

Comment: @Werner This was my first vision: characters  0.2 pt tall. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I've completely misunderstood the problem, here's a version that inserts text into a "rule" by using a `\colorbox` of appropriate width instead of an actual LaTeX rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\rulebox[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \fontsize{5}{5}\selectfont
    \fboxsep0.5pt%
    \colorbox{black}{\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\textcolor{black!80}{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\rulebox{Some hidden text here}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a higher magnification, the hidden message (if that was intended) becomes readable:

[image]