# Justify text / image and InsertBoX

Tags: spacing, insbox

I am trying to write a report where I write text around images (sometimes on the left, sometimes on the right). Then I want to integrate center justified images, titles, etc.
I am using the commands \InsertBoxL and \InsertBoxR and it works well.
However, I don't konw how to justify the text and images I have after that. It is like it creates a "margin" and the image is then "centered" in the remaining space.
I am looking for an advice. You will find below and image as well as the code.
Can you please let me know if you have any idea?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\input{insbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337070/how-to-insert-a-text-in-rule
\newcommand\rulebox[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
    \fboxsep3pt%
    \colorbox{orange}{\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\textcolor{black!80}{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
}

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\center
\textbf{\Large Information 1}
\newline\medskip
\noindent\rulebox{Title 1}
\justify{
\InsertBoxR{0}{\quad\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Images/co2.png}\quad}
La \color{orange} concentration de dioxyde de carbone \color{black} (CO2) dans l’air intérieur dépend à la fois de l’occupation humaine et du niveau de renouvellement d’air. Le taux de CO2, témoin du confinement de l’air, est considéré comme une valeur contrôle de la qualité de l'air intérieur. En effet, un renouvellement de l'air inadapté implique une dégradation de la qualité de l'air intérieur puisqu'à l'instar du CO2, les autres substances présentes dans l'air intérieur ne sont pas évacuées. Par ailleurs, une concentration élevée en CO2 suscite de l’inconfort pour les occupants et peut s’avérer néfaste pour la santé. Encadré par le décret n° 2012-11 du 5 janvier 2012, l'indice ICONE prend en compte à la fois les fréquences de situation de confinement, mais également leur intensité et s'exprime sur une échelle de 0 à 5.}
\center{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Images/ANTOINE_panel_39.png}}
\newline
% *********************************
% ********     Confort         ************
\noindent\rulebox{Confort des occupants}
\newline
\justify{
\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{Images/weather.png}}
La \color{orange}température \color{black} recommandée pour des activités sédentaires se situe entre 19 et 22°C. D'une façon générale, les jeunes enfants ont une capacité de régulation thermique faible, une surface cutanée proportionnellement plus importante que celle des adultes  et une peau plus fine. Garantir une bonne ambiance thermique est un enjeu pour le confort mais également pour la santé.}
\center{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/ANTOINE_panel_34.png}}
\justify{
\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{Images/rain.png}}
Le \color{orange}taux d'humidité \color{black}relative recommandé se situe entre 30 et 70\%, idéalement entre 40 et 60\%. Un air trop sec assèche les muqueuses des voies respiratoires, favorise les crises d'asthme pour les asthmatiques, infections ORL pour les tout-petits, sensation d'inconfort pour les autres. Les taux d'humidité élevés favorisent par ailleurs les émissions de formaldéhyde par les matériaux intérieurs. Cette situation favorise également la prolifération de moisissures et d'acariens.}
\center{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/ANTOINE_panel_40.png}}

\end{document}
% END THE DOCUMENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the structure of your document isn't good.

1. Don't use the commands `\center` and `\justify`. They are meant to be used as environments, not commands. Instead of `\center{xxxx}` use

```tex
    \begin{center}
        xxxx
    \end{center}
```

or `{\centering xxxx}` (**Note:** braces around, not inside.)

Similar for `\justify`, but as this is the default, you don't need it here.

2. You must properly close your paragraphs, preferably with an empty line, or with `\par`. If you don't the indentation caused by the `\Insertbox` will not be properly closed.

So here is an improved version (I could not test it with your images, of course, so I tested it with standard images).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\input{insbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337070/how-to-insert-a-text-in-rule
\newcommand\rulebox[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
    \fboxsep3pt%
    \colorbox{orange}{\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\textcolor{black!80}{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
}

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Large Information 1}
\end{center}
\medskip
\noindent\rulebox{Title 1}

\InsertBoxR{0}{\quad\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Images/co2.png}\quad}
La \color{orange} concentration de dioxyde de carbone \color{black} (CO2) dans l’air intérieur dépend à la fois de l’occupation humaine et du niveau de renouvellement d’air. Le taux de CO2, témoin du confinement de l’air, est considéré comme une valeur contrôle de la qualité de l'air intérieur. En effet, un renouvellement de l'air inadapté implique une dégradation de la qualité de l'air intérieur puisqu'à l'instar du CO2, les autres substances présentes dans l'air intérieur ne sont pas évacuées. Par ailleurs, une concentration élevée en CO2 suscite de l’inconfort pour les occupants et peut s’avérer néfaste pour la santé. Encadré par le décret n° 2012-11 du 5 janvier 2012, l'indice ICONE prend en compte à la fois les fréquences de situation de confinement, mais également leur intensité et s'exprime sur une échelle de 0 à 5.

\begin{center} 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Images/ANTOINE_panel_39.png}
\end{center}

% *********************************
% ********     Confort         ************
\noindent\rulebox{Confort des occupants}
\newline

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{Images/weather.png}}
 La \color{orange}température \color{black}
    recommandée pour des activités sédentaires se situe entre 19 et
    22°C. D'une façon générale, les jeunes enfants ont une capacité de
    régulation thermique faible, une surface cutanée proportionnellement
    plus importante que celle des adultes et une peau plus fine.
    Garantir une bonne ambiance thermique est un enjeu pour le confort
    mais également pour la santé.

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/ANTOINE_panel_34.png}
\end{center}

\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{Images/rain.png}}
Le \color{orange}taux d'humidité \color{black}relative recommandé se situe entre 30 et 70\%, idéalement entre 40 et 60\%. Un air trop sec assèche les muqueuses des voies respiratoires, favorise les crises d'asthme pour les asthmatiques, infections ORL pour les tout-petits, sensation d'inconfort pour les autres. Les taux d'humidité élevés favorisent par ailleurs les émissions de formaldéhyde par les matériaux intérieurs. Cette situation favorise également la prolifération de moisissures et d'acariens.

\begin{center} 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/ANTOINE_panel_40.png}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```